# Resolving 'Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal' when Folder Redirection is active

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-xp

Our Windows Forms application by default saves data files in a user's 'My Documents' folder (on XP) or 'Documents' folder (on Vista). We look up this location by calling:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal )
```

We know for sure this works great for users whose personal folder is on a local disk. What we're not sure about is domain users who have Folder Redirection in effect for their profile/personal data folders.

My question is: **Does the above call properly resolve regardless of whether Folder Redirection is active?**

I don't have the environment to test this out, and I haven't been able to find any definite confirmation one way or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.  You can test this out yourself by updating the corresponding registry entry for the folder.  Look under ...

```
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\
```

Comment: I know that changing the target of the 'My Documents' folder will update this registry key (and, consequently, the Environment.SpecialFolder' call will work correctly).

But does Folder Redirection work in the same way?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a user reporting the following error on an `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` call on an XP machine whose My Documents is redirected to the network (it goes to drive O):

```
System.ArgumentException: Absolute path information is required.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
   at System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder, SpecialFolderOption option)
   at System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder)
```

I haven't had direct access to this machine configuration yet, but from google searches and the user's help, I believe the redirect is lacking a trailing \ (eg. O: instead of O:\).

So I believe the answer would be **no, it doesn't correctly resolve everytime**.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that it does.  The documentation for both `Environment.GetFolderPath` and the underlying [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204(VS.85).aspx) don't give any indication that it would not resolve correctly nor can I find anything that you would use its place.